# Column space of a linear model

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

Suppose I have the following linear system of equation

$$X = AC$$
with $X$ of dimensions $N \times T$, $A$ of dimension $N \times D$ and $C$ of dimension $D \times T$.

Does it hold in general that $\mathcal{R}(X)= \mathcal{R}(A)$?

My line of thought is the following, but I would like to have some comments and further explanation on it.

Clearly $\mathcal{R}(X) \subseteq \mathcal{R}(A)$, since each column of $X$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$. Now, if $C$ is invertible, then I can write $XC^{-1}=A$, and hence each column of $A$ is a linear combination of the columns of $X$. Thus $\mathcal{R}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{R}(X)$. In this particular case ($C$ invertible), then $\mathcal{R}(X)= \mathcal{R}(A)$. But does it hold in general?

Also, I did not talk about rank and so on. Is the rank going to influence the above conditions?

**SVD view**

If we take the SVD of $X$, and we consider its economy size $X= U\Sigma V^\top$ with $\Sigma$ a diagonal $D \times D$ matrix, the matrix $U$ forms an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{R}(X)$. How is this orthonormal basis $U$ related to $A$? What are the relationship between the SVD of $X$ and  the matrix $AS$ as in $ U\Sigma V^\top$ with $\Sigma= AS$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, we have $\mathcal{R}(X) \subseteq \mathcal{R}(A)$ (and correspondingly, $\operatorname{rank}(X) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A)$). It follows that we have $\mathcal{R}(X) = \mathcal{R}(A)$ if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(X) = \operatorname{rank}(A)$.

With that said, it is easy to see that equality will not hold in general. For example, if $T < N < D$ and $A$ has rank $N$ (i.e. "full row rank"), then the rank of $X$ is at most equal to $T<N$, which means that the ranks cannot be equal.

One *sufficient* condition for equality of rank (and hence of ranges) is that $C$ has linearly independent rows (i.e. "full row rank"); notably, this can only occur if $D \leq T$. In this case, $C^+$ (the Moore-Penrose inverse of $C$) satisfies $CC^+ = I$, which means that we have
$$
\operatorname{rank}(X) \geq \operatorname{rank}(XC^+) = \operatorname{rank}(ACC^+) = \operatorname{rank}(A),
$$
which together with the other inequality implies that $\operatorname{rank}(X) = \operatorname{rank}(A)$.

Comment: Related to " $\mathcal{R}(X) = \mathcal{R}(A)$ if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(X) = \operatorname{rank}(A)$", I was thinking: the fact that equal rank means equal subspace, it is only because I cannot "go out" of the subspace generated by A through the linear combination of its column. Right? 
Also: if instead we would have a tall matrix $A$ full column-rank and a wide $C$, we would have that $X$ has the same rank as $A$ again only if $C$ has independent rows?

Comment: @VanBaffo Right. So in other words, if $U$ is a subspace of $V$ with $\dim(U) = \dim(V)$,  then it must hold that $U = V$. To your second question, the answer is yes. The rank of $AC$ is at most equal to the rank of $C$, which is equal to the number of rows in $C$ iff $C$ has independent rows, and the number of rows in $C$ is equal to the number of columns in $A$, which is equal to the rank of $A$.

Comment: @VanBaffo On a tangential note, when $A$ has full column rank and $C$ has full row-rank, the product $X = AC$ is called a [rank-revealing factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization) of $X$.